# Google apps script. putting a variable as parameter

Tags: google-apps-script, parameters

I have to write a script that should automatically create documents. It takes information from two different spreadsheets. let's call this spreadsheet "A" and spreadsheet "B". To give the script input on where to find the names and addresses to put in the document, I created a third spreadsheet spreadsheet "C". In this spreadsheet I enter 6 pieces of information by hand: "pZahl", "kZahl", "start", "end", "euro" and "fahrtK". Then the script should get the names and addresses from Spreadsheet "A" and Spreadsheet "B" at the locations I entered for "pZahl“ and "kZahl" in Spreadsheet "C" and insert them into the document.

```
function myFunction() {
  //getting info
  var templateDLV = 'templateDoc';
  var pZahl = Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.get('SpreadsheetC', 'B2');
  var kZahl = Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.get('SpreadsheetC', 'B3');
  var start = Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.get('SpreadsheetC', 'B4');
  var end = Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.get('SpreadsheetC', 'B5');
  var euro = Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.get('SpreadsheetC', 'B6');
  var fahrtK = Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.get('SpreadsheetC', 'B7');
  
  pZahl = pZahl.values;
  kZahl = kZahl.values;

  Logger.log(pZahl);
  Logger.log(kZahl);
//the following is where the problem is
  var kDaten = Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.get('SpreadsheetA', kZahl);
  var pDaten = Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.get('SpreadsheetB', pZahl);
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById('FolderA');
  

  
  //copy template
  var documentId = DriveApp.getFileById(templateDLV).makeCopy().getId();
  DriveApp.getFileById(documentId).setName('DLV-' + pDaten.values[0][1] + '-' + kDaten.values[0][0]);

  //insert Text
  var doc = DocumentApp.openById(documentId);
  var body = doc.getBody();
  body.replaceText('##kVor##', kDaten.values[0][0]);
  body.replaceText('##kNach##', kDaten.values[0][1]);
  body.replaceText('##kStr##', kDaten.values[0][2]);
  body.replaceText('##kNr##', kDaten.values[0][3]);
  body.replaceText('##kPlz##', kDaten.values[0][4]);
  body.replaceText('##kOrt##', kDaten.values[0][5]);

  body.replaceText('##pVor##', pDaten.values[0][1]);
  body.replaceText('##pNach##', pDaten.values[0][2]);
  body.replaceText('##pStr##', pDaten.values[0][8]);
  body.replaceText('##pNr##', pDaten.values[0][9]);
  body.replaceText('##pPlz##', pDaten.values[0][10]);
  body.replaceText('##pOrt##', pDaten.values[0][11]);


  body.replaceText('##start##', start.values);
  body.replaceText('##end##', end.values);
  body.replaceText('##euro##', euro.values);
  body.replaceText('##fahrtK##', fahrtK.values);
  doc.saveAndClose();

  //create PDF
  var pdf = folder.createFile(doc.getAs('application/pdf'));
  pdf.setName('DLV-' + pDaten.values[0][1] + '-' + kDaten.values[0][0]);

}
```

Comment: The sample code looks a bit weird to me. `Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.get()` Does it suppose to work at all? Could you describe in more detail your workflow?

Comment: Probably you tried to use the samples from the API help: https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/get but that's a whole nother story. Somehow I belive you don't want to use Sheets API.

Comment: Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.get() returns an object. Within that object is a property called values and within values is a property called range.  so the variable is kZahl,values.range

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand your question, I proposed a modified script as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your question and that was not useful, I apologize.

Comment: @NickAutomatic Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill, again. Unfortunately, I cannot still understand your actual question. But I understand that my proposed answer was not useful for your situation. First, I have to delete my answer. Because I don't want to confuse other users. This is due to my poor English skill. I deeply apologize for this again. But I would like to try to understand it. When I could correctly understand it, I would like to think of the solution. I would be grateful if you can forgive my poor English skill.

Comment: @Tanaike I tried to explain my problem more specific and postet my whole code so you could see what i am trying to do. I hope it easier to understand now.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer:
with the code `pZahl = pZahl.values;` the content was still in an array. I extracted it using `pZahl = pZahl.values[0][0];`. Same for kZahl of course.
Now it works perfectly fine.